# Database offline control (prevent data conflict when back to online)

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, overwrite

Sorry, I am a newbie programmer with insufficient database control knowledge.I am not sure whether now i need to redesign the whole system flow or add on some feature in it.

Currently I have a few client that running on different computer.

Current Architecture:

***-When the network is on,***
Each clients will update into a same server, then server will sync data back to all local database located in each client.

***-when the network is down,***
Each clients will access to the local database, and save their update list, until they are reconnect back to the server, the update list will pass to server and will doing update to the server again.

The architecture is doing fine when the customer will only use one of the client (once), so the update apply to same customer only apply once and therefore no data conflict is occurred.

***Now the problem come,*** one of the new feature of the system, like appointment function, if one of the appointment type is fail, customer is allow to make appointment again but not the type he had failed before.

But if system is down, customer is allowed to make the appointment with the same type again and he might success on the second try and the record will delete the previous failed information/ or if this information is updated before the client that holding the failed record connecting back to the server, the old record will overwrite the new record.

Currently i have some idea but i hope some one here will give me a guide, either other design or some other precaution should i take on this flow.

***Some of the idea:***

1. If the system is down, some function that might cause conflict should be not allowed.

-(Yet this is somehow decrease the availability of the system)

2. The update list will only work until all client is reconnected to the server, It compare which data is fresh and conflict, and will choose the fresh data to update and flag up the conflict.

-(Somehow i think it is the worst idea.by binding the client all together and restraint the update list to update in time, we can't confirm the data in server is the latest and might cause more problem to those online client. )

3. When the connection is flag down, record down all the update in another table. Just use some program/excel? to compare and check on the conflict?

-(probably the idea that cost the most)

Is there any third party software that can help on my situation?Or I should just change the system flow on updating and retrieving the data?

Comment: More often than not you need to manually cater for it by using some form of locking - much like you see in source control - otherwise you leave the customer/client app to sort out the conflict - which is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Sort of.  Notify the "victim" that their update will not be successful, as someone else has updated (maybe even mention the updatee).  Keep track of the last value and make sure it is still the same before updating.  Won't be perfect though.

Comment: hmm, is it mean by comparing the time and decide which record to update? because if two client offline together, would it be possible they get the same version of data in their local? if they online in different time, it mean that the sql pass to update list is not conflict as no same data to be compare and though the update is done in different time BUT is already overwrite each other?

Comment: When the client offline, it is still functioning, since it is not connected to the server, how would i make it know the current version is outdated and is not allow?

possible the customer is already done with the update and i think is quite impossible to ask him back for the registration after we notice as it might increase up to thousands customer.

Comment: If i wish to implement the app to sort out the conflict, i think it is required all client to be online again, and though it can't ensure the freshness of the data in the server already i guess? ouch, or actually I am doing some prevention that is impossible to be done T__T